# Best practice - blocking confirmation-by-mail abuse

Tags: javascript, authentication, spam-prevention

This is the first time I'm building a website with complex login\signup dialog with backend security feats such as email validation with an activation code and ban registration for too many bad login attempts.

I thought I was finished with building the security architecture, but then this came up: How do i block malice users from abusing my new user dialog.

The only solution I could come up with was a cookie handed at the moment of a successful registration with email address that was last used for registration, backend recognizes this cookie on a new registration attempt and prompts the user about the new findings. Maybe even takes a timeout before responding.

But that only makes it intolerable for 12 year olds, it probably wouldn't happen, but someone with even basic skills and good enough reason could brute register thousands of emails with a simple script, I cannot block a user from having as many accounts on my website as he does have email accounts (amirite?)

Any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK, no online service stops that from being happen.

Comment: +1 Great question. Wish more people would worry over this sort of thing...

Comment: do your users submit the data via a html form or ajax?

Comment: @andrew I'm using Angulars $http.post method, I understand it's ajax. Docs say: "The $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP."

Comment: This is called [rate limiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting). Indeed, neither cookies nor (clientside) javascript can protect you against this.

Answer (score 1):

Try integrate a Captcha code or something the user has to do, e.g. a small math. Randomly generate something the user has to do to be able to register. Usually this annoys most kiddies because they would have to change their scripts.

Captcha code is usually something pretty common on public website registration pages...

Also maybe try to register email together with the IP and log IP addresses logged in on that account and prevent new accounts for that IP.

Answer (score 1):

You could record the IP address on registration and if you get a high amount of users from the same IP address you could block it.. saying that spammers can spoof their IP.

I would recommend:

- CSRF
- Verifying email address.
- Record all IPs and block any if necessary.
- If all fails CAPTCHA, it won't flush out everything but it kills a lot in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to generate a random number server side and store it in a session variable which must be returned along with the data, or better still some hashed version of the random number eg. md5. This can be verified by the server.

This means that you only get one attempt per request, kiddies would have to adjusted scripts to suit your site. You could even restrict the frequency at which the numbers can be generated per session.